# How can I make automatic lighting in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been trying to create a redstone system for my "town" on multi-player and was using some guides on creating automatic lighting using redstone, water, and pistons, but it is not working properly and I am looking for some more extensive guides on how to do this.

Ideally, I would like the lights to come on at night and go off during the day. I have used Etho's Light Sensor and followed other peoples modifications to it to make it work. However, they do not seem to work properly. When the piston is supposed to retract, it doesn't.

Comment: does the redstone deactivate?

Comment: I can't see how we can help you.

Comment: You've probably messed up the BUD switch or killed your grass.  If that's the case, you pretty much have to start over.

Comment: It's quite hard to debug this kind of thing without at least some screenshots or diagrams of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you want an alternative method, use villagers. Just create a small shack with a villager and a door. You can make it really small, and hook it up with pressure plates.

Now villagers will go outside as soon as it get light, and will go inside again when it gets dark. Using this system you have a day-night system.

To make it a little secure you can fence the shack in, leaving just a small space for him to roam around.

If you need some more details feel free to ask, I kept my explanation extremely basic.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Found a simple guide online to do this and it works more effectively for me.

Comment: Brilliant idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the on-off= off system 
daylight sensor red wire 14 blocks redstone repeater-redstone torch then put this to your lighting system. it works because light night light cant go very long. make sure output can protect light sensor. Does work

Comment: To clarify, the daylight sensor will be in the 1.5 update and is not in the current 1.4.7 version.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as an existing one.  We try not to duplicate answers here.